# Use model method in class and override that method

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a method called complete in my model, how can i use that in my class view, in my model method there is one parameter called person which is being passed i do not want my
overriden method to use that parameter how can i acheive that.

```
class Mymodel(models.Model):

     is_done = model.BooleanField()
    
     def complete(self, person):
         self.is_done = True
         self.save(update_fields=['is_done'])
         self.done_by.add(person)


class MyView(SomeView):
    def complete_record(self):
        return Mymodel.complete(here it expects two arguments i need only self)
```

and i want to get rid of self.done_by.add(person) in model's complete
method

Answer (score 1):

The `complete()` method can be called for a single model instance (a single object of the queryset).

In the View, maybe you want to do this if you have a id param in url:

```
instance = Mymodel.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['id'])
instance.complete()
```

or the scenario can be this if you are using DetailView:

```
self.get_object().complete()
```

-- EDIT --
If you want to set `is_done = True` without add person and
if you can't edit model class, you can put the logic in the view:

```
class MyView(SomeView):
    def complete_record(self):
        record = Mymodel.objects.get(pk=id)
        record.is_done = True
        record.save()
        return record
```

Comment: I am do it it the first way but here i am do not want the person as parameter and  i want to get rid of self.done_by.add(person) in model's complete method while i am using this in my view as i will not have person as argument.